# Merge data with partially matched filename

Tags: batch-file, merge, match

I have many data file with partially matched filenames，such as

```
T70M1U1-cell.txt
T70M1U1-anode.txt
T80M5U1-cell.txt
T80M5U1-anode.txt
...
```

"T70M1U1-cell.txt" contains

```
A
B
C
```

and
"T70M1U1-anode.txt" contains

```
1
2
3
```

I want to combine two dataset into one "T70M1U1.txt" containing:

```
A    1
B    2
C    3
```

How would I batch merge two data set "T70M1U1-cell.txt & T70M1U1-anode.txt" and others like that using a batch or software?

Comment: Is the `T70M1U1` part always 7 characters in length, or could it vary?

Comment: yes，always 7 characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd "dir\containing\txtfiles"

for %%I in (*-cell.txt) do (
    set arr.length=0
    set file=%%~nxI
    set dest=!file:-cell.txt=.txt!
    if exist "!dest!" del "!dest!"
    for /f "usebackq" %%a in ("!file:cell.txt=anode.txt!") do (
        set "arr[!arr.length!]=%%a"
        set /a "arr.length+=1"
    )
    set idx=0
    for /f "usebackq" %%a in ("%%I") do (
        >>"!dest!" call :dump %%a !idx!
        set /a "idx+=1"
    )
)
goto :EOF

:dump
echo %1 !arr[%2]!
```

In the last line, that's supposed to be a tab between `echo %1` and `!arr[%2]!`, but you can use whatever delimiter you feel is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET source=c:\sourcedir
SET dest=c:\destdir
FOR /f "delims=-" %%a IN (
 'dir /b/a-d "%source%\*-cell.txt"'
 ) DO IF EXIST "%source%\%%a-anode.txt"  (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%p IN ('findstr /n /r "$" ^<"%source%\%%a-cell.txt"') DO (
   FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%s IN ('findstr /n /r "$" ^<"%source%\%%a-anode.txt"') DO (
   IF %%p==%%s >>"%dest%\%%a.txt" ECHO %%q %%t
   )
  )
 )
```

All you appear to need to modify are the source and destination directories to suit your situation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it doesn't work well after I modify the directories, could you examine it cause I am not familiar with batch.

Comment: I'll just get out the ol' crystal ball... The mists are clearing... the spirits say that it would have been better to say exactly what directories you chose or how the evil black screen responded or even what you mean by "not work well". Their best guess is to invoke the spell of quotation - try `set source="yoursourcedir"` for both `source` and its twin, `dest`, since it is not unknown for the treacherous editor to add trailing spaces to a batch line, rendering the path incomprehensible for the `cmd.exe` genie...

Comment: Sorry for my unclear description. I tried to add quotation to `source` and `dest`    `set source="d:\source" ` and The black screen shows nothing, also there is no txt file in "d:\dest". When I add `echo %%p` in the line 8 `FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%p IN ('findstr /n /r "$" ^<"%source%\%%a-cell.txt"') DO ( echo %%p`, the screen shows nothing.

Comment: Try changing line 7 ` ) DO IF EXIST "%source%\%%a-anode.txt"  (` to ` `) DO echo %%a&IF EXIST "%source%\%%a-anode.txt" ( echo %%a-anode exists` which should show which *-cell files are detected and whether or not a corresponding -anode exists. I'd suggest that the `-` in the `delims` clause may be missing, making `%%a` the full filename. OR that the `-` in `a-d` is missing, which would cause the `dir` to atempt to list (non-existent) directories rather than NOT disting directories.

Comment: Changing the line 7, the screen shows `T70M1U1
T70M1U1-anode exists`. Also there is no file in 'dest'. It seemed that the problem is in the line 8.

Comment: Seems that we're detecting the files but `findstr` is having difficulties. Works perfectly for me, btw. I've tried changing the target string for findstr to `"^"` (beginning of line) and `"."` (any character) as well as `"$"` (end of line) but had no change in my results. I've also tried all three `regex` characters with `SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` but that changed nothing. This is quite intriguing - what happens if you try `findstr /n /r "$" <"%source%\some-valid-data-file-name"` ?

Comment: I've changed the code to `findstr /n /r "$" <"%source%\T70M1U1.txt`, and the results is the same as before.

Comment: Hmm - I'd intended that you execute `findstr /n /r "$" <...`  from the prompt. If `...` was an actual filename like `T70M1U1-cell.txt` then I'd have expected the file to be reproduced with each line numbered `1:line1/2:line2` etc. I don't know where your *-cell.txt reside; that's why I preceded the name with %sourcedir% - so the full pathname to the file would be specified. I also don't know whether your pathname contains spaces - that's why I enclosed the ENTIRE filename in quotes (the last is not in yours), which is required so that `CMD.EXE` knows it's one string, not separate parameters.

Comment: When execute `findstr /n /r "$" ^< d:\source\T70M1U1-cell.txt` from the prompt, the screen shows `d:\source\T70M1U1-cell.txt:1:1,...`. The pathname do not contain space. Changing the bat file to above code, it  does not work as before.

Comment: Be very careful. `findstr /n /r "$" ^<d:\source\T70M1U1-cell.txt` will generate a heap of junk. `findstr /n /r "$" <d:\source\T70M1U1-cell.txt` is what I asked you to do. The difference is subtle. FROM THE PROMPT **WITH** the caret (`^`) you get junk. **WITHOUT** you get the file applied to `findstr`.  HOWEVER in a batch file, within the `FOR /f...` you NEED to add the caret - it escapes the redirector `<` and tells `CMD` that the `<` is part of the `command to be executed`, not a redirection into the `FOR` itself. Same way as you use `FOR %%x` within a batch but `FOR %x` from the prompt.